# Missing csproj file - Recreate/regenerate one

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, csproj, sln-file

I took over an ASP.Net application from a co-worker. It is not MVC; it is a web pages application. There is no *.csproj file in the application at all. How can I create one? The solution has a line like this:

```
Project("{guid}") = "AdminSite", ".", "{guid}"
```

The `*.*` in the middle is where the `AdminSite.csproj` should be written. The file does not exist on disk or in source control.

Comment: Why does right click -> add new project then add in all the files not work?

Comment: Honestly I thought if I added a new project and dragged files around I'd break NuGet mappings, etc. And the new project would have a different name and hence possibly mess up name spaces. I'll give this a shot though.

Comment: Yeah - that fubared the whole thing. Had to revert from source control.